# How I can use replace and then make new rows in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, separator

I each row of my data frame I have a couple of words. they has been separated by `,` . I want remove `,` if there is a space after that in all rows. and then make new row where I have `,`.

For example let I have:

```
title               id
A, home,sad, Kar    1
car,figth, Sumer    2
light,daad,Hi       3
```

There is space after  `,`  in the first row after `A` also after `sad` . in the second row after `figth`. and the last row is good. so I will make new row with rest and will keep their `id`.

```
title               id
A home              1
sad Kar             1
car,                2
figth Sumer         2
light               3
 daad              3
 Hi                3
 park              3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `str.replace` + `str.split` followed by `explode`:

```
df.assign(title=df['title'].str.replace(r',\s', ' ').str.split(',')).explode('title')
```

---

```
         title  id
0       A home   1
0      sad Kar   1
1          car   2
1  figth Sumer   2
2        light   3
2         daad   3
2           Hi   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with positive look forward:

```
df.assign(title=df.title.str.split(',(?=\S)')).explode('title')
```

Output:

```
          title  id
0       A, home   1
0      sad, Kar   1
1           car   2
1  figth, Sumer   2
2         light   3
2          daad   3
2            Hi   3
```

Comment: you didn't remove extra `,`?

Comment: @elham No, you can choose to replace the remaining `,` with `''`  afterwards.

Comment: Can I ask you how you copied the sample data into your system using `pd.read_clipboard()` ? Because there are some `spaces` between `title` column.

Comment: @ashkangh use `sep='\s\s+'` for more than one space separator so you ignore ` ` within the columns.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much!